# JavaScript: How to run a table tag before div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run a table tag before div tag so that it will be input for the second one that is div.

I have created a dynamic table using JavaScript and then i have created a graph for it.

I want a table data as source data for graph, so I have used a button onclick function for it, it works fine as table is created first then when i click on button it activates a function and creates graph, but if i make graph default it shows null because table is creating the same time when graph so, is there a way to run table firstly and after that graph div without using button.

This is how i have create a table
javascript

```
function writeln(str) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.appendChild(tbdy);
  var temp = new Array();
  temp = str.split("  ");
  var tr=document.createElement('TR');
  tbdy.appendChild(tr);
  for (var zxc2=0;zxc2<temp.length;zxc2++){
    var td=document.createElement('TD');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(temp[zxc2]));
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}

function main(){
tbdy=document.createElement('TBODY');
writeln(...String...);
...}
```

html

```
 <div id="graphcontainer"></div>
 <table class="highchart" id="output" data-graph-container="#graphcontainer" data-graph-type="line" data-graph-height="300">
  </table>
```

Comment: How is the table created? What's the JavaScript for doing all this?

Comment: What does this mean ? **trying to run a table firstly**. Sorry i am confused. You should show us some code you tried.

Comment: I do not see where `tbdy` is defined. I suspect that no Table is being appended.

Comment: it is defined in main function for a tbody as global variable from where i am calling this function @Twisty

Comment: Is your code rapped in `jQuery(function () { /*... your code */})` so it doesn't run until the document is ready?

Comment: @Victory no its not wrapped in jQuery function

Comment: put a global variable in your code like tableCreated=false check on graph load tableCreated?showGraph:disposeGraph. Make variable true or false when you creates a table.

Comment: @Atul Can you elaborate it. i didnt get you what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @iamsujit declare one variable as i said. when you initialize your graph check whether table created or not. if not graph will not initialize. When you create a table make tableCreated true then your graph initialize and gets table data.

Comment: or create fiddle link i will try

Comment: @Atul fiddle link is showing error for post request. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsujit/uve649ke/1) you can try here [demo](http://mahavarkar.in/new_amort.html)